# Access git files at specific commit/branch using PHP

Tags: php, git

Is there any chance to access/read files (for example documentation files) *virtually* at a specific commit/branch using PHP?

My goal is to create a doc page where you can easily switch the version of files to see what was changed (to non-tech people).

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/libgit2/php-git

Comment: Saw this one but couldn't figure out if this works the way I need it to

Comment: It does. See if the docs help: https://libgit2.github.com/docs/guides/101-samples/

Answer (score -1):

I don't think so. As far as I know, the only way to switch commits is with `git` or on github. However, you could have the different versions stored on the latest commit and have links to them, but that will use a lot of space.

Sorry if I am wrong, I am not an insane git expert.

Comment: OP just needs to `show` a specific revision, not `checkout`. It is sufficient to look at how `git-show` does it with `libgit` and mimic it.